# Combine two pd.DataFrames and check for duplicate Data ('lastname', 'name')

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I have multiple .xlsx or .xls files which contain addresses. 
Sometimes those lists have multiple sheets.
My python scripts starts by reading all excel-lists and their sheets and append them togheter

```
    excel_files = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls' or f[-4:] == 'xlsx'] 
    for excel_file in excel_files: 
         excel_obj = pd.ExcelFile(INPUTFOLDER+excel_file) 
         sheetnames = excel_obj.sheet_names 
         for sheets in sheetnames: 
              sheet_data = pd.read_excel(INPUTFOLDER+excel_file,         
              sheet_name=sheets) 
              df = df.append(sheet_data,sort=False)
```

After this step i have the following columns:

`Index(['Land', 'Firma', 'Anrede', 'Vorname', 'Nachname','Straße', 'PLZ','Ort', 'Briefanrede', 'Name'],dtype='object')`

Now i got columns dupllicates. "Nachname" and "Name" contain the lastnames.
So next step is to check this and append them togheter.

`if 'Name' and 'Nachname' or 'Lastname' and 'Name' or 'lastname' and 'name' in df.columns:`

But i dont know how to put them togheter and delete the remaining empty column.
I will provide a example in a google sheet:

[example excel sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TenG8V9NTc3YQReEsx8KRV_q6s8Hjy9MwpK0Lm4t6qQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: df['Lastname'] = df['Nachname']+df['Name]? Then drop both Nachname and Name using df.drop(columns=['Nachname', 'Name'])

Comment: Seems not to work as expected. use the provided example to test https://imgur.com/FjKW8jv

Comment: When i concatenate lastname + name and then pop name. lastname only contains nan´s. https://imgur.com/zyGKaLv